# Creating new 2D array from a slice of 3D array in python?

Tags: python, arrays, sorting

[image]

I have a 3D array [256,256,450] that I would like to fetch a 2D array from a cross section along the z axis. The new 2D array should start at z=0 at the top and have the values across some i'th y slice for x =0 to x=255. Then the next row in the new 2D array should be the same for z=1, and so on until z=449. How can this be done?

Comment: Would you like to take a layer from a 3D array? Can you please show an example of the array?

Comment: What does this have to do with sorting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
array_3d = np.ones((256, 256, 450))
y_layer = 24 # arbitrary y layer
array_2d = array_3d[:, y_layer, :]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use NumPy's [NDArray class](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.html) and [slicing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html?highlight=slicing) syntax.

```
import numpy as np
my_array = np.zeros([256, 256, 450]) # 256x256x450 array
... # Do whatever you want to do to load data in
x_slice = my_array[0,:,:] # A 256x450 array, the first element in x
y_slice = my_array[:,0,:] # A 256x450 array, the first element in y
y_slice = my_array[:,99,:] # A 256 x 450 array, the 100th element in y
```